# three.js - rendering tube geometry in intervals

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Tube Geometry(Three.js) , I dont want whole tube to be plotted and rendered at one time but want it to happen after some interval (or timer). How can I render some part of tube then after some interval continue plotting from the same point further ?

Comment: I got it but I am re rendering points everytime for eg : First rendering 100 points and then 0 to 200 points then 0 to 300  and so on .. But can I add next 100 points to first 100 points so that I render only 100 points everytime ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use either setInterval() or setTimeout(); for a description of how to use these, see

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Note that these are functions provided by JavaScript, not Three.js.

Comment: I m using setInterval but problem is that it will again plot all the points from starting at each interval. I was thinking if we can plot one set (100 points in one interval) then next 100 in next interval  (not like 200 points in next interval)